# Finding conditional probability with Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

While I tagged this question homework, it's not really homework. I'm really studying for a test and don't understand how to do something. I have the answer to the question, so the important part is for my to understand how to get there.

X has distribution `Gamma(2,4)`
`X = Y-3` Find: `P(Y>11|Y>7)` Which I know is equals to:

`(1-P(X<8))/(1-P(X<4)) = (1-Fx(8))/(1-Fx(4))`

I have been told that `Fx(a) = 1-e^(-a/4)-(a/4)*e^(-a/4)`

So I can clearly solve the problem now it's just algebra. **But how do we know what Fx(a) equals???**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_x(a)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a [gamma$(2,4)$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Probability_density_function).  This is given by $$F_x(a) = \int_0^a \frac{t e^{-t/4}}{(4^2)\Gamma(2)} dt.$$ 
Integrating (by parts) yields the given expression for $F_x(a)$, since $\Gamma(2) = (2-1)! = 1$.

Comment: O.K. so it seems as though the best way in general to do this is know that P(x<a) = integral of the probability density function evaluated at a?

Comment: @kralco626: In general, yes, although when you find the integral make sure you include the lower bound as well as the upper bound.

Comment: how do i know what the bounds are? is this because gamma is only for `x>0`. Also is `Γ(x)` always `(x-1)!`?

Comment: @kralco626: Yes to your second question, which implies the answer to the first.  As far as the third, when $x$ is a non-negative integer, $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$.  Otherwise, see the definition of the gamma function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition.